# Not reading all mailitems from Inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

PLease see code below.  The subroutine I've written is supposed to look at all the emails that have come in just today and move only those that have the subject "daily stats".  I've deliberately sent two emails to myself with the subject "daily stats".  There is one other email in the Inbox that doesn't have the appropriate subject.  In all there are three emails.  When the Sub MoveHarpStatMail runs, it only moves one of the right emails with the subject "daily stats".  The other one seems to be ignored.  Is there something screwy with my filter string?  I've used the exact same filter string in another subroutine and it works perfectly fine there, reading in all the emails that came in just today.  I think I need another pair of eyes that will point out where I've gone wrong.

Alan

```
Public StatsArchiveFolder As Outlook.Folder
'StatsArchiveFolder is set elsewhere in another subroutine
Public Const SubjectTitle As String = "daily stats"
_______________________________________________

Sub MoveHarpStatMail()

Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
Dim olappns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oitem As Object
Dim ItemsToProcess As Outlook.Items
Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim sFilter As String
Dim tempMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

On Error GoTo LocalErr

'set outlook objects

Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
Set olappns = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = olappns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
'Filter for only MailItems received today
sFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= " & AddQuotes(Format(Date, "ddddd"))
Set ItemsToProcess = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Restrict(sFilter)

For Each oitem In ItemsToProcess
 If TypeName(oitem) = "MailItem" Then
   Set tempMailItem = oitem
   Debug.Print tempMailItem.Subject
   If CheckSubject(tempMailItem.Subject) Then
     MoveToArchiveFolder tempMailItem
   End If
 End If
Next oitem

ExitProc:
Set olapp = Nothing
Set olappns = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set ItemsToProcess = Nothing

Exit Sub

LocalErr:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
     Msg = "Sub MoveHarpStatMail" & vbCrLf & "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
         & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
     MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
     End If
End Sub

____________________________________________

Private Function AddQuotes(MyText) As String
  AddQuotes = Chr(34) & MyText & Chr(34)
End Function

_______________________________________________

Sub MoveToArchiveFolder(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

    If StatsArchiveFolder Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox ("The ArchiveFolder object is not set.")
    End If

    Item.Move StatsArchiveFolder

End Sub
________________________________________________

Function CheckSubject(Subject As String) As Boolean

  If LCase(Trim(Subject)) = LCase(Trim(SubjectTitle)) Then
    CheckSubject = True
  Else
    CheckSubject = False
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Hello again! Have you checked how many items, and which ones, are in `ItemsToProcess`?  Also have you checked which ones get passed to `MoveToArchiveFolder`? In general, you need to step through your code using F8 and/or add more `Debug.Print` statements. Also, I wonder if it would somehow work better if you just passed oitem to `MoveToArchiveFolder`? I don't really see the need for `tempMailItem`.

Comment: You have a variable that you initialize but don't use.  Namely myFolder. Try changing `Set ItemsToProcess = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Restrict(sFilter)` to `Set ItemsToProcess = myFolder.Items.Restrict(sFilter)`

Comment: The suggestion to use debug.print statements did help to a point.  If I replace the call to MoveToArchiveFoler with a debug.print statement, then the loop iterates properly over 3 mailitems.  If I leave the call to MoveToArchiveFolder, the loop iterates only twice, moving only one mailitem with the subject "daily stats" and then exits the loop ignoring the last third mailitem with the subject "daily stats". I urge you to try it yourself using my code.  I don't get why it is exiting prematurely. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your loop is exiting "prematurely" because you're the loop increments each time through, and you're decrementing the stack (`ItemsToProcess`) at the same time, so you'll naturally skip over about half of your items.
To avoid this, you can loop through from the top to the bottom using something like this:

```
For i = ItemsToProcess.Count To 1 Step -1
```

and use `i` as the index for referencing the MailItems.

Comment: +1. By Jove, I think you've got it! It's just like deleting rows.